# Main menu in windows phone 7 on xna framework

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone-7.1

I am writing a game using xna for wp7 for the first time and finding difficult to implement main menu and managing game state. please provide any tutorials/links.

I searched on SO, found below link but the this link is broken.
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

Comment: [Here is the fixed version of your link](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management). But is there an actual question here? What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wanted to know the Game state managmnt and game menu implementation (a tutorial or a link), as i am new to WP7 game dev world and only i can write main game logic/loop but additional screens. i think now i would be able to. thx again!

Answer (score 0):

Try the Nokia developer site:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Windows_Phone/Code_examples/

They have some good examples on XNA.

Do you know that you can mix XNA and Silverlight? i.e. Menus can be in Silverlight while your actual game screens can use XNA.

Comment: Thanks for great samples. Yes, know a little on SLXNA but not sure about the implementation, i think its only runs on Mango(7.5). Please pass some implementation info.

Comment: I am actually not a game developer but I did put together a basic structure of a game with menu and game screen by using the Space Blok XNA sample from the above mentioned website. Hope that helps.